# php class constants with bitvalues

Tags: php, oop, bit-manipulation

Can classes have bitshifted values defined as class constants / static variables ?

I want to implement a permission system similar to the one described here http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/bitwise.htm (sorry best example I could find from a quick google)

For example ive tried this

```
class permissions {
const perm1 =1;
const perm2 =2;
const perm3 =4;
//--CUT--
const perm24 =8388608;
```

const perm25 = perm1 | perm2;

} which gives

```
syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ',' or ';'
```

and the preferred way

```
class permissions {
static $perm1 =1<<0;
static $perm2 =1<<1;
static $perm3 =1<<2;
//--CUT--
static $perm24 =1<<23;

static $perm25 = $perm1 | $perm2;

}
```

which gives

```
syntax error, unexpected T_SL, expecting ',' or ';'
```

The latter way works outside of a class environment eg

```
$perm1 =1<<0;
$perm2 =1<<1;
$perm3 =1<<2;
//--CUT--
$perm24 =1<<23;

$perm25 = $perm1 | $perm2;
echo $perm25;
```

Giving the expected 3 (2+1) (or 2^0 + 2^1)

What is the best way to define this in a class ?

Comment: USe the __construct method for that

Comment: `$perm1 =1<<0;` isn't defining a constant; it's defining a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

bitwise or logical operations qualify (like mathematical operations) as not permitted

Comment: Pointed me in the right direction I'm using hex notation now to keep it readable but achieve a similar thing

Comment: Much cleaner way of doing it